# Laravel default auth register how can i insert data into two different table

Tags: php, laravel, web, web-deployment

I am new to laravel and i want to insert the data into two different tables using one form submission. Example i want to insert the user's account info into "tbl_users" (e.g. Email, Password) and the user's info will be inserted into "tbl_client" (e.g. Name,Bday,Address).By the way i am just using the laravel default auth register (User.php, RegisterController.php). Is there is a safest way to do that ?.

---

**User.php**
[image]

---

**RegisterController.php**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers). You can then on `saved` or `saving` of the user model, create a new client, from there filling it with the data used to create user. You could use the global `request()` to get the submitted data.

Another way would be, on model construct create a new client from there. So in your `user.php` model, something like:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes)
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    new Client()
}
```

and then proceed to fill the client.